# In Javascript: Losing type of object when passed from Array?

Tags: javascript

I'm passing an object of a certain type to an array.
When I print the object from an outside reference I can see all the fields.
When I print the same object from the array reference, I see almost none.

To Explain, here is the code that illustrates the problem:

```
var test = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();

var array = [test];

console.log("******* Printing Test directly ***************");
printObjectProperties(test);

console.log("****** Printing Test from array **************");
for (obj in array){
    printObjectProperties(obj);     
}
```

The `printObjectProperties()` function:

```
function printObjectProperties(eventData) {
        for (var prop in eventData) {
            if (!(typeof (eventData[prop]) == "undefined")) {
                console.log(prop + " = " + eventData[prop]);
            }
        };
}
```

The complete code (complete html file, you can run and see for youself in the browser console log):
([live example](http://jsbin.com/evazip/2/edit))

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var test = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();

        var array = [test];

        console.log("******* Printing Test directly ***************");
        printObjectProperties(test);

        console.log("****** Printing Test from array **************");
        for (obj in array){
            printObjectProperties(obj);     
        }

    });


function printObjectProperties(eventData) {
        for (var prop in eventData) {
            if (!(typeof (eventData[prop]) == "undefined")) {
                console.log(prop + " = " + eventData[prop]);
            }
        };
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It is more helpful if you create a jsFiddle demo. I made one: http://jsfiddle.net/tu6er/

Comment: Thanks. I actually created a demo, search for "live example"

Comment: :) Must have missed that... ;)

Comment: Why don't you just pass the object/array to `console.log` instead of trying to format it yourself? Try this and you'll see all the properties: http://jsbin.com/evazip/3/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Btw. it's already in the answers, but nevertheless: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: @Ben: `for...in` is used to loop over properties of objects. It is much slower than a `for` loop. For more reasons to not use it for arrays, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `for in` loop, the first variable (`obj`) is the key. In an array that's the index.

So basically you're iterating over a number in `printObjectProperties`. Hence the `0 = 0`, because the first index of your array (you have one element) is `0`.

Use this instead:

```
printObjectProperties(array[obj]);
```

which would evaluate to:

```
printObjectProperties(array[0]);
```

or:

```
printObjectProperties(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't iterate over an array using for in:

```
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```